# How to add a day to a year,month,day datetime object

Tags: python-2.7, loops, datetime

I found similar posts but had issues with them.
The problem I have is:
I have a date in the format year, month, day example - 2019:01:21
and I want to use a loop likely something like
for i in range(365):
       # add to the date by a single day and return something in the form 2019:01:22

Answer (score 0):

You could use [datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to parse the given date in string format to a python date format. Then you could use [datetime.timedelta()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to specify an interval of n days and shift the parsed date by this delta. Here is a short demo:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

date = datetime.strptime("2019:01:21", "%Y:%m:%d")

for i in range(365):
    delta = timedelta(days=1 + i)
    print(date + delta)
```

Output:

```
2019-01-22 00:00:00
2019-01-23 00:00:00
2019-01-24 00:00:00
...
```